# Using mono assemblies from the .NET CoreCLR

Tags: linux, mono, dnx, .net-core, coreclr

I need to consume a library that doesn't yet have CoreCLR support (RabbitMQ.Client, to be specific). Is it possible to utilize a mono-based port of that library on a Linux system from inside a CoreCLR executable? If so, how is that achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible at binary level (unless using a proper PCL profile). .NET Core has a different approach to arrange classes in assemblies, so some assemblies on desktop .NET Framework are broken into smaller assemblies, and types are moved. A desktop targeting assembly (from .NET or Mono) won't work on .NET Core due to such changes.

But it is obviously possible at source code level, as there was an attempt to port Mono's WinForms to .NET Core,

http://forums.dotnetfoundation.org/t/anyone-porting-winforms-mono-to-net-core/898/4

Once a new .NET Core library project is created, the source files should be able to be carried over (with some modification or even none).

However, .NET Core has been evolving too fast, and that attempt might be now out of date. Anyone would like to explore in this area can follow that example and try once again. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks... that information may come in handy if I embark on porting the library from Mono to CoreCLR. But my question is really about whether I can just use an existing Mono assembly "as-is" within CoreCLR, or if porting the code to a CoreCLR project and rebuilding is absolutely necessary.

Comment: It is very much impossible, as .NET Core has a different assembly hierarchy, so the references change, the types are moved. Some PCLs might work, but the classic class libraries won't.

Comment: OK, thanks. Please update your answer to reflect what we discussed in these comments, and I'll go ahead and accept it.